# Is there a installable Travis alternative?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

Is there a CI server that works similarly to Travis that is installable?
I want to test mainly Python applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which continuous integration server is able to queue jobs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747463/which-continuous-integration-server-is-able-to-queue-jobs)

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth uhm.. not really

Comment: It's not the same question, but the poster wanted Python, so I think it comes down to the same thing. Feel free to be more specific why not.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I understand the OPs question like: "Which self-hosted CI solution comes closest to Travis?". The focus is not on a specific feature or the fact that is should work for python. More importantly the solution should be similar to Travis in as many aspects as possible and easy for a Travis user to pick up. Even though the tools suggested in the answers of both might show certain commonalities, IMHO the two questions are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

[Buildbot](http://buildbot.net/) and [Jenkins-CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) are two solutions that will meet your needs.

Buildbot is a Python application - Jenkins-CI is written in Java but can run tests for Python programs.

Answer (score -1):

[Bamboo - Continuous integration, deployment & release management | Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) is another alternative, but it would be discontinued.